# Why does a page in WordPress need to be published before it appears in the menu?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I would like to keep my site private while I am building it, but the menu will not appear unless the pages are published, which seems odd. Am I missing something?

Comment: Not odd at all. If anything, it's probably by design: posts/pages with status Draft are not meant to be publicly visible, hence the reason why you can't add them to the menu. Why not develop your new sections/features on a [staging site](https://wpengine.com/resources/what-is-a-staging-site-why-have-one/) instead?

Comment: @cabrerahector, you should elaborate on that option in an answer; I believe it would solve the OP's problem nicely.

Comment: Thanks for replying but I am still confused,if anyone else would like to chuck in any suggestions that would be welcome:)

Comment: @Techtard, sorry for the late response. Just now seeing your reply. Can you elaborate on what your issue is? The menu you are talking about: is this in the admin section or on the front page of the site? What about future publishing, have you tried that? Like, set the date to January 1 2029 or something?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their replies,I sorted the problem now.